# hello, need to show Download app on mobile site

Tags: magento-1.9, app, amazon

I have to download app on top bar when user is on mobile site(theme).
Just like Amazon,

See the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

finally I have found the answer and have posted on here.

https://github.com/gaurangpadhiyar007/Show-Install-Android-Iphone-App-Script